# Cognito Authorization with Azure AD SAML integration returns id_token and access_token but no refresh token

Tags: azure-active-directory, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-js

I have a cognito User Pool with 1 client that is configured with 2 identity providers, `Cognito User Pool` and a SAML provider that links an Azure AD instance. The `Allowed OAuth Flows` is set Implicit grant only. Login via the Cognito User Pool provider is done using the `InitiateAuthCommand` in the `@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider` library. From this an id_token, access_token and refresh token are all returned.

Login via the SAML provider is done by using the template link provided in the cognito developer docs (https://your_Amazon_Cognito_userpool_domain/authorize?
response_type=code&identity_provider=your-SAML-IdP-name&client_id=your-
client-id&redirect_uri=https://your_application_redirect_url). This login works, however only an id_token and access_token are returned (no refresh token).

How can I get cognito to issue a refresh token for users logged in via the SAML provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cognito should not return a *refresh token* for *Implicit grant flow*. That is the intended behaviour according to the [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2.2):

> The authorization server MUST NOT issue a refresh token.

Also using the implicit flow is [highly discouraged](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/implicit/) due to vulnerabilities.

Please consider using Authorization code grant flow along with PKCE. With that you can get the *refresh token*.

The reason you get the refresh token along with the `aws-sdk` is, because it should be using a different Auth flow (example: `USER_PASSWORD_AUTH`) as mentioned in the [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cognito-identity-provider/interfaces/initiateauthcommandinput.html#authflow).