# AWS Cognito to retrieving refresh token after Google authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

I'm using AWS Cognito for authentication and authorisation in backend API's. If user sign in using Cognito, I get `access token`,`id token` and `refresh token`.
In this scenario i will use id token for authentication and authorisation purpose. If the id token expires I will use `refresh token` to generate new tokens.

But, if I use Google as Identity Provider. After successful user creation, I'm getting  only the `access token` and the `id token`. Its expiry is 1 hour also. After 1 hour how can i maintain user authentication in this scenario ?

Is it possible to generate refresh token after Google authentication from Cognito ?

This is the url I'm using for Google signup/signin :

```
https://{DOMAIN_NAME}.auth.{REGION}.amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=token&client_id={CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=http://localhost:5000/
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cognito Authorization with Azure AD SAML integration returns id\_token and access\_token but no refresh token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74787236/cognito-authorization-with-azure-ad-saml-integration-returns-id-token-and-access)

Answer (score 0):

According to your sign in URL, you are trying to use *Implicit grant flow* here (because `response_type=token`).

Cognito should not return a refresh token for Implicit grant flow. That is the intended behaviour according to the [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2.2):

> The authorization server MUST NOT issue a refresh token.

Also using the implicit flow is highly discouraged due to [vulnerabilities](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/implicit/).

Please consider using Authorization code grant flow along with PKCE. With that you can get the refresh token.

The reason you get the refresh token along with Cognito, UserName/Password is because it should be using a different Auth flow (example: `USER_PASSWORD_AUTH`).